# How to make a HTML list appear horizontally instead of vertically using CSS only?

Tags: html, css, menu, positioning, horizontallist

I need this because I want to make a menu (which is made from a HTML list) appear horizontally.

I prefer not to use absolute positioning since it might become messy when I start changing the layout of the page.

I would like also to remove the indenting of the sub-lists. Is it possible?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You will have to use something like below

```css
#menu ul{
  list-style: none;
}
#menu li{
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>First menu item</li>
    <li>Second menu item</li>
    <li>Third menu item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Will (display:inline;) remove the indenting for the sub-lists?

Comment: No. For that, you want `#menu li li{margin-left: 0; padding-left: 0;}`

Comment: Like a charm had to tweak it a bit for my use-case but a solid answer.

Answer (score 23):

Using `display: inline-flex`

```css
#menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-flex
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>1 menu item</li>
    <li>2 menu item</li>
    <li>3 menu item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Using `display: inline-block`

```css
#menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#menu li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>1 menu item</li>
    <li>2 menu item</li>
    <li>3 menu item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 13):

quite simple:

```
ul.yourlist li { float:left; }
```

or

```
ul.yourlist li { display:inline; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use inline styling something like this

```
<ul style="list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
  <li style="display: inline">A</li>
  <li style="display: inline">B</li>
  <li style="display: inline">C</li>
  <li style="display: inline">D</li>
</ul>
```