# Trying to get a menu to go inline with html and css

Tags: html, css

I have created a menu list in html using a  list, i have added the list to a div called menu. In my css I have added display:inline to try and make the list to display the list inline, normally this works but for some reason it doesn't seem to work.

**Here is my Code**

```css
#menu ul {
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background: white;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">

  <ul>

    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a>
    </li>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <li><a href="about.php">About Us</a>
    </li>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <li><a href="Specials.php">Specials</a>
    </li>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <li><a href="terms.php">Terms</a>
    </li>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a>
    </li>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;

  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a HTML list appear horizontally instead of vertically using CSS only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145181/how-to-make-a-html-list-appear-horizontally-instead-of-vertically-using-css-only)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put display inline on your ul li not ul since you only have one :)

So change your css to this:

```
    #menu ul li
{

 width: 100px;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
 background: white;
 padding-top: 20px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style:none;
 display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want the list items to be inline:

```
#menu ul li{display:inline-block;}
```

or

```
#menu ul li{float:left;}
```

or

```
#menu ul li{display:inline;}
```

But don't forget to clearfix the float for the 2n option.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to apply the `display: inline` to `li`. Also remove the `position: absolute` from `ul`

```css
#menu ul {
  width: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: white;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
}
#menu ul li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">

  <ul>

    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a>
    </li>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <li><a href="about.php">About Us</a>
    </li>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <li><a href="Specials.php">Specials</a>
    </li>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <li><a href="terms.php">Terms</a>
    </li>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a>
    </li>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;

  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the next code, it will work for you. I've removed the `&nbsp` and update the css to apply the rules to `li` element.

```css
#menu li
{
  width: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: white;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  list-style:none;
  display:inline;
}
```

```html
<div id ="menu">

<ul>
    
 <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li> 
 <li><a href="about.php">About Us</a></li> 
 <li><a href="Specials.php">Specials</a></li> 
 <li><a href="terms.php">Terms</a></li> 
 <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li> 

</ul>

</div>
```

I hope that helps :D

Answer (score 0):

You have to put select the li instead of the ul. Also you have a width of 100px in your ul that doesn't let the li's to spread.

```
#menu ul {
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 1;
     background: white;
     padding-top: 20px;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     list-style:none;
}

#menu ul li { display: inline; }
```