# Angular NgFor Elements Displayed Horizontally as Tags

Tags: html, css, angular

I currently have a [search feature](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-course-filter-pipe-mbb53i?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) that allows users to add search filters.  E.g. if I add `linear algebra`, `probability`, and `data science`, the view will display a vertical list of each filter and an anchor tag:

```
<div *ngFor="let term of searchTerms"> 
  <div style="display: inline-block;"> {{term}} </div>
  <a style="color: indianred; display: inline-block; padding-left: 6px;" (click)="removeTerm(term)">✖</a>
</div>
```

I'd like to display these elements horizontally, and I've looked into [angular/flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/API-Documentation), but it is not compatible with the angular version `4.4.5`

I've tried making each term a list element and wrapping it in a menu div and altering the CSS (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2145208/6521206) but this does not work either.

Secondarily I'd like to display the terms through some cleaner looking chips ([for example](https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview)).  I've looked into some [chip alternatives](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-chips) but these seem to be too heavyweight for my purposes.  Is there a simple bootstrap or CSS implementation that offers a simple tag [like this one](https://materializecss.com/chips.html)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
<div *ngFor="let term of searchTerms"> 
  <div class="badge badge-primary"> {{term}} </div>
  <a style="color: indianred; display: inline-block; padding-left: 6px;" (click)="removeTerm(term)">✖</a>
</div>
```

If you want more stylish you can use button also.

Comment: Thank you for sharing, is it possible to get these elements to display horizontally?  using bootstrap or otherwise?

Comment: Use bootstrap version 3

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap the closest thing to a chip is a badge - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/badge/

Answer (score 0):

After searching bootstrap documentation and using user suggestions, I've put together this solution:

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class="row">
          <div class="list-inline">
             <div *ngFor="let term of searchTerms" class="col-md-2" style="padding: 7px;">
                <div class="list-inline-item">
                    <span class="badge badge-pill"> {{term}} <a (click)="removeTerm(term)">✖</a>  </span> 
             </div>
          </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```